# Is there any Java framework similar to EXT.net and Unigui?

Tags: java, extjs, ext.net

i am looking for extjs integration with java similar to Unigui from http://unigui.com for pascal users or the one for c# users  EXT.net.

Answer (score 0):

While it is not direct answer to your question as far as I can tell there is nothing similar to uniGUI for Java, but you may consider switching to Delphi & uniGUI if your project specs are compatible.